# $y=3x^2$ AND $y=30-x$ To The Right Of x=1, About The Y-Axis. find the volume by shell method

Tags: calculus

$y=3x^2$ AND $y=30-x$ To The Right Of x=1, About The Y-Axis. find the volume by shell method

We used to find $V=\int ^b_a 2\pi x f(x) \;dx$ is this right can any help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

With shells, you want to make thin tall strips to rotate, like making rolls of toilet paper. So your small change is going to be $dx,$ your height is going to be $f(x)$ and the length of each "roll" is $2\pi r$. If you unfold each revolution of this toilet paper roll ananlogy, it's ... well, a strip of toilet paper, so the total volume is length times width times height: $2 \pi r f(x) dx.$ To make a toilet paper roll, you ADD the varying lengths of the toilet paper. Hence the integral.

Now the hard part, where do you start and stop $x,$ and what is $r$? Since you're rotating around the $y$ axis, the length to the edge of your strip is whatever the $x$ coordinate is all up and down that fixed, vertical strip. But $x$ is what you're varying (we're using $dx,$ remember) so keep it as $x.$ Nothing fancy.

Where do we start? $a=1$ as the problem tells us. We should stop where the two curves $30-x$ and $3x^2$ intersect TO THE RIGHT OF $x=1.$ We have that $3x^2=30-x$ so that $3x^2+x-30=0.$ That factors into $(x-3)(3x+10)=0.$ So you should stop at $b=\frac{10}{3}.$

Draw out what you see and trace what I said in words. Visualize it and rewrite my answer as your own. Check my arithmetic!

Comment: ...how it going to be b=10/3